# Can rules rule (as in govern)?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I've seen people say things like "the rules that rule Japan", but I don't think it is grammatically correct since rules can't really enforce themselves and the verb 'rule' can only really be used for humans.

I do like the sound of "rules that rule", is it really not grammatically correct?

And if not, is it at least common enough that one could use it in a book?

Comment: Is it possible that you're being too literal?

Comment: I think that maybe what's bothering you is the style choice to repeat "rule" within the same sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can, especially if the speaker is suggesting that it is the rules that govern and not any specific person or people, as people--politicians, kings, whoever--come and go but the rules remain, steadfastly imposing themselves on the citizenry to such effect that they normatively conform.

By the way, that's an example of an antanaclassis.  An antanaclassis is a rhetorical device in which a phrase or word is repeated, though the meaning changes in each case. It is the repetition of a similar word in a sentence with different meanings, or a word is repeated in two or more different senses.

https://literarydevices.net/antanaclasis/#targetText=Antanaclasis%20is%20a%20rhetorical%20device,two%20or%20more%20different%20senses.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a wonderful explanation and exactly what I need to know!

Comment: Good answer. I think you hit it on the head with the Rules that Govern.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Nancy

in "rules **rule**"
rule(s): (noun - a word to identify a thing)order, guideline, law  etc
**rule**: (verb - a word to describe an action)order, instruct, require, command, regulate etc.

EXP: "rules rule" = orders order = guidelines instruct= law require